# Compare 2 versions a of table in big-query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanted to compare 2 versions of a table.
I wanted to compare Before last modification with latest data from a table.
here i have a sample sql script which compares the tables

```
WITH
before_mod AS (  SELECT *
              FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB`
              FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB({{ lastModification }}, INTERVAL 2 second)),
after_mod AS ( SELECT * FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB` ),
row_changed AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM before_mod EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT *
  FROM after_mod
)
SELECT * FROM row_changed
```

This SQL first will create a CTE for

1. before_mob -> this holds a snapshot of the table as it was on that specific point in time.
2. afrer_mod -> the actual data in the tableB

Then "row_changed" table is created by selecting all rows from "before_mod" that are not in "after_mod".

The problem is that bigquery does not allow to use diferent timestamp `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS ...`

Exception:`If a 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF' expression is used, all references of a table should use the same TIMESTAMP value.`

I also tried adding the before_mod in a view and then query the view SQL below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `big-query-112.temp.tableB_before_mod_temp` AS (
              SELECT *
              FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB`
              FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB('2023-02-04 13:12:35 UTC', INTERVAL 0 second)
        );
WITH
before_mod AS ( SELECT * FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB_before_mod_temp`),
after_mod AS ( SELECT * FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB` ),
row_changed AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM before_mod EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT *
  FROM after_mod
)
SELECT * FROM row_changed
```

The problem with this one is that it is not showing the rows that are different, seams that is getting in table from only a specific time.

Also, cannot use `materialized view` Exception: `Invalid value: Materialized view query cannot reference historical versions of the table definition`

Is there a way how can i compare 2 versions of the table, without creating a copy?

NOTE: Table does not have an ID (in the way the table is being generated it is hard to add an id which is always same for a specific row)
also querying the `` SELECT * FROM `big-query-112.temp.tableB_before_mod_temp `` shows the expected results

Comment: Timetraveling (SYSTEM_TIME) can only be at a position in time. A direct comparision to current data is not possible. Workaround: Save the timetravel query to a new table, then compare both tables.

Comment: I see, just wanted to avoid copying the table

Answer (score 0):

I suggest treating it as two different tables. Avoiding copying the modified table is way better but formulating a workaround for that is quite obscure.

You can try this code after you create and copy your modified table.

```
SELECT a.domain
FROM [Table1] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [Table2] b
ON a.domain = b.domain
WHERE b.domain IS NULL
```

Comment: I do not have an id in table, and i try doing that join using another field which may have more than one value it will duplicate the data.